# What photoconducting materials/metamaterials reach full conductivity within 1/30th of a picosecond

Tags: material-science, conductors, optical-materials

I'm doing research on photoconducting materials/metamaterials but I'm having a hard time finding confirming how fast they reach full conuctivity, What photoconductors reach full conductivity and back again within 1/30th of a nanosecond? Any resources(such as websites) where I could hope to find a photoconductor with this reaction time would be useful as well...

Comment: The real question is, what exactly are you trying to do? Then some answer might be possible.

Comment: Google stuff like "transient transport dynamics of photoexcited carrier in semiconductors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the substance I was looking for:

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/64523/

It's called *low temperature grown* GaAS, It is an excellent photoconductor at the frequencies I need.